# PostgreSQL table corrupt not display in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgresql, spatial-database, table

I have a problem with a PostgreSQL table. It is the result of a query that joins 77 tables with 4 columns (geom, inicio, fuente, temporada). I used ST_SRID and ST_Transform because I could not join tables with different SRID.

When I want to export it as shapefile QGIS can not display the file, it does not recognize it. I tried to insert a column ID_0 but the problem continues.

Consulting on this table resulting some sub tables and I could export as a shape, but not others. I do not know if the table is missing some metadata, or did something wrong with the reprojection.

Comment: is geom column a collection of multiple geometry types?

Comment: No, they're all polygons. The problem was that some shapes had values of M and Z and joined those layers with others that hadn't that values.
So I removing the M and Z values of some shapes with ArcMap and reprojecting other tables with QGIS to unify the projection of the final table in PostgreSQL, I could finally unite all the tables and export them as a single shape in QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

- Layers With M and Z values alter the final table.
- ST_Transform did not reproject layers well (for SRID 0).
- I chose to export layers in a table with the same projection, reproject them with QGIS to SRID 4326 and to rejoin all the layers in the table and with that it worked.